# Push an object into the internal array of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I want to push an object into the internal array of an array.

My array:

```
[{"roomid":"652994","Listener":[],"broadcaster":[]}]
```

I want to push the following object inside `Listener` array:

```
{"name":"jony","age":"26"}
```

To become:

```
{"roomid":"652994","Listener":[{"name":"jony","age":"26"},{"name":"pear","age":"32"}],"broadcaster":[]}
```

Comment: You should simply assign the array to a variable, and access it `const a = [...]; a[0].Listener = {"name":"jony","age":"26"}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the first index of the array to access the property `Listener`, then `push()` the object:

```
arr[0].Listener.push(obj);
```

```js
var arr = [{"roomid":"652994","Listener":[],"broadcaster":[]}]
var obj = {"name":"jony","age":"26"};
var obj2 = {"name":"pear","age":"32"};
arr[0].Listener.push(obj, obj2);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just push it where you want it to have:

```js
var array = [{
  "roomid": "652994",
  "Listener": [],
  "broadcaster": []
}]

var toPush1 = {
  "name": "jony",
  "age": "26"
}

var toPush2 = {
  "name": "pear",
  "age": "32"
}

array[0].Listener.push(toPush1);
array[0].Listener.push(toPush2);

console.log(array);
console.log({
  "roomid": "652994",
  "Listener": [{
    "name": "jony",
    "age": "26"
  }, {
    "name": "pear",
    "age": "32"
  }],
  "broadcaster": []
});
```